# Limit a global scope augmentation

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to limit a module's global scope augmentation only to those that import it directly?

```js
// lib/foo.ts
export default true

window.FOO = 60

declare global {
  const FOO: number
}
```

```js
// bar.ts
import './lib/foo'
export const BAR = FOO
```

```js
// main.ts
import { BAR } from './bar'
console.log(BAR, FOO) // how to make FOO be unavailable here?
```

Comment: If you declare it global, it’s global

Comment: Try `declare global {
  interface Window{const FOO: number}
}`, access it through `window.FOO`

Comment: @leili Thanks but I wonder if there's a way to use window.FOO on bar.ts but not see it on main.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By including the types through `tsconfig.json` rather than importing them,
the inclusion can be limited only to the lib directory.

```
// lib/tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [
    "foo.d.ts",
    "bar.ts",
  ],
  ...
}
```

<sub>NOTE: files not included shall be handled by the parent `tsconfig.json` I assume.</sub>

---

Once the side effects and global scope augmentation have been split,

```js
// lib/foo.ts
window.FOO = 60
```

```js
// lib/foo.d.ts
export default true
declare global {
  const FOO: number
}
```

the global augmentation takes place only on the selected lib files.

```js
// lib/bar.ts
import './foo'
export const BAR = FOO // FOO is defined
```

```js
// main.ts
import { BAR } from './lib/bar'
console.log(BAR, FOO) // FOO is not defined
```

This is more a workaround than a solution. One of the many downsides, for example, is that `lib/bar.ts` can't expose any type from `lib/foo.d.ts` (derived or not) since its not being included in the parent program. Thankfully in my use case these globals were only needed to aid the module's internal implementation but never for its external API.

---

##### EDIT

Better yet on some other cases, alongside `bar.ts`, we can have a `bar.d.ts` which includes `foo.d.ts`